# Extract one to many relationship. Extract all data from first table including all data from second table

Tags: mysql, extract, one-to-many

[Database Structure][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2zeX.png

This is what I try
`SELECT m2101_claim_form.*, m2102_expenses_list.title FROM m2101_claim_form INNER JOIN m2102_expenses_list ON m2101_claim_form.id = m2102_expenses_list.m2101_id WHERE m2101_claim_form.id = 1`.
What I have received were three arrays. What I am looking for is one array inside with three arrays.

```
[0] => {
    id: 1
    detail: 1
    amount: 150
    },
[1] => {
    id: 1
    detail: 2
    amount: 250
    },
[2] => {
    id: 1
    detail: 3
    amount: 350
    }
```

to

```
[0] => {
     id:
     [0] => {
         detail: 1
         amount: 150
     },
     [1] => {
         detail: 2
         amount: 250
     },
     [2] => {
         detail: 3
         amount: 350
     }
}
```

Can someone help me pls. I have tried INNER JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and LEFT JOIN. But the outcome still the same.